Error using aws_ssm_parameter in terraform
What I am intending to do:
Add an AWS SSM parameter containing a range of IPs to be used in terraform
What I've done:

Created a StringList parameter in the SSM Parameter store called "range_of_ips", the value in that parameter is written like this: "192.168.15.0/24", "172.17.2.0/22" and so on.
Added the following to terraform (in my data.tf file):

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "range_of_ips" {
  name = "range_of_ips"
  type = "StringList"
}

Then used this later in the terraform code like this (in my locals.tf file):
my_ip_ranges = [data.aws_ssm_parameter.range_of_ips]

I am getting the following error during validation:

type = "StringList"
│
│ Can't configure a value for "type": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.**

this is the latest error as I have tried variations of StringList, "StringList", and adding ARN to the data resource...  different errors every time.
What is the correct way to do this?  The documentation isn't clear.  Is it not possible?

You don't specify a type when using the datasource to lookup the parameter value. The type was specified when you created the parameter, and the datasource is going to automatically use whatever type you chose at that time. You would only specify type if you were using the Terraform resource to create the parameter via Terraform.

You cannot set the type as the error says:

type = "StringList" │ │ Can't configure a value for "type": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

The documentation might be a bit confusing if you're just starting, but in this particular case it says the following:

In addition to all arguments above, the following attributes are exported:
type - Type of the parameter. Valid types are String, StringList and SecureString.

This attribute gets exported, meaning you can use it later on in your code if needed. Based on the very limited example you have provided, I think the following should work:
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "range_of_ips" {
  name = "range_of_ips"
}


Makes sense.  Yes I've only been working with/ learning terraform for about 5 months now.  I work in security and have been working on trying to create a 'simulated' business environment in AWS (desktops, servers, etc).  I'm using terraform to spin up and tear it down as needed.  So far so good, but I'm now 'refining' the code and using things like parameters rather than hard-coding.  running in to problems like this, but in most cases I can figure it out with the errors.  Thanks for the reply!

Btw, since you're new to StackOverflow, please take a look at this article: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979.
